# Get information about device by `ttyUSB*` path on Debian

Tags: usb, debian

Got 2 identical GSM modems. When I connect them both, sometimes after reboot, they are being switched (first one is second and second is first). So I need to get serial number or something similar.

Second thing is that modem opens 3 ports... for exaple USB0, USB1, USB2 ... and only one of them is really usable to GSM communication... any way to detect that without trying to connect with device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0`. Also, you should have `/dev/serial/by-*/` with automatic symlinks based on device path, serial number, and other parameters; try `ls -lR /dev/serial`.

Comment: `udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0` returns `missing option`, but second option works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0 returns missing option, because its incomplete comamnd
We can complete it as mention below:

> [root@localhost ~]# udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/ttyUSB0
>
> Output:
>
> /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/ttyUSB0/ttyUSB0

or

> [root@localhost ~]# udevadm info --query=symlink --name=/dev/ttyUSB0
>
> Output:
>
> char/188:0 serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.3.2:1.0-port0 serial/by->id/usb_Intel_0123456789ABCDEF-if00-port0